# Set-Cookie from header is not being sent as Cookie in the following requests in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am doing a POST request in python using requests library then i am getting multiple set-cookies in the response headers out of 4 i got only 2 are being sent as cookies in my subsequent request.

```
response = session.request("POST", url1, data=payload1, headers=headers1,verify=False,cookies=previous_response.cookies)
```

When i send request as mentioned above all the set cookies from previous request headers must set as cookies but only few of then are being set

For eg

```
Set-Cookie: sp_ac=AQB1uO6eg3fKauhLNID7uLdT9wuD_9Qy-FtXYhfl68sGO4YkUL2tKpY_EXlV_SKvngDccQOI5BaKSdycCA5U-7h1N5LQ7HH5wjQbGXSB6o7pcKBvhRXsBne4zHSSFsdExwBQ0m_AwVo9d8UjkfUXiGtStI8vvF-p9ZJctNSrqf14DFh1juqZpK3cV_AplvJDVGgZEnALUa6JrBQJLZLXrUnDM4aBvPT9qNc;Version=1;Domain=accounts.spotify.com;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: sp_dc=AQDCboRdqnDFFtXA8px3gqjA3UkFXu5ikby1DsKg6D3v3LkholwIGSZizDHnSGuFHieuTsitpr8ubYApjQRaH2asYAuQGdzJ69zuzjPU8g;Version=1;Domain=spotify.com;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Mon, 22 Jun 2020 13:03:15 GMT
Set-Cookie: csrf_token=AQB0q1XS7kZ5saul8QVL-7NIZVqrrAeeXW5OQUzjys8SQXTLUBf9M2wNOOQeyGU2cB-assn4XKqB9vRx;Version=1;Domain=accounts.spotify.com;Path=/;Secure
Set-Cookie: sp_key=59071bcb-664c-4302-b98b-6ba15d54f605;Version=1;Domain=spotify.com;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000;Secure;Expires=Mon, 22 Jun 2020 13:03:15 GMT
```

these are my previous response headers

In my next request only 2 are being sent, i dont know the reason behind it and to how to solve it

```
Cookie: sp_dc=AQDCboRdqnDFFtXA8px3gqjA3UkFXu5ikby1DsKg6D3v3LkholwIGSZizDHnSGuFHieuTsitpr8ubYApjQRaH2asYAuQGdzJ69zuzjPU8g; sp_key=59071bcb-664c-4302-b98b-6ba15d54f605
```

this is my new cookie header in new request

Comment: What is the hostname in the URL of the subsequent request?

Comment: I resolved it is a same host but with different sub domain

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured out the answer after lot if research the hosts seems to be different

So what i have done is make a small notification in the post

Instead of this

```
response = session.request("POST", url1, data=payload1, headers=headers1,verify=False,cookies=previous_response.cookies)
```

I changed the cookies to dict so that it would be host independent as follows

```
response = session.request("POST", url1, data=payload1, headers=headers1,verify=False,cookies=previous_response.cookies.get_dict())
```